# Angular HtmlCollection displaying less items on console, whereas on expansion more items are displayed which could not be captured by code

Tags: angular, elementref

**strong text**There is a library which on reference dynamically create a table , i want to get the scrollheight of this table
But when I do:
`console.log(this.ElByClassName.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('tbody'));`

is showing

[image]

and on displaying the length its showing zero ,

but on expansion of this HTMLCollection I can see three array items , which i could not capture on using index , Does anyone has any idea why its so?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are probably trying to get log of the elements before they were addd to the DOM. Try adding your log (or the logic you want to apply to the elements) to some other lifehook of the Angular, like `ngAfterContentInit()`. If you get your elements through subscription, reference them from there when you know they're received.

Comment: Not working in that life cycle hook also.

Comment: Trying to access in this life cycle hook but same isssue

Comment: Then I guess you're getting your table data from some subscription, maybe to api or some other service? It would be best to share the relevant code.